# Will pyinstaller support more packages soon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyglet

I'm trying to convert pyglet to .exe using pyinstaller but it is not supported, I was just wondering if pyinstaller is still being developed and if more packages will be added soon to the supported list? I tried using cx_Freeze but I could not wrap my head around it.

Comment: Like basically any open source project, pyinstaller support for a particular package is likely going to be added by someone who needs it.  If you have time and skills, they take pull requests: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pulls

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you, but unfortunately, I'm new to python and I don't have the skills to add it myself.

Comment: To answer part of your question (is pyinstaller still being developed?): you can view the "Insights" tab on any github repository to see how frequently contributions are being made to a project: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/graphs/code-frequency